# Batch File not starting automatically as a service

Tags: batch-file

i am having trouble while starting a batch file as a service. the batch file runs fine when started manually but it doesnt starts a service and no ouput is observed. i have used nssm service manager to start the service.

below are the commands which i have used :

```
D:\nssm-2.24\win32>nssm install call
D:\nssm-2.24\win32>nssm start call
```

while installing i have provided the path of batch file.

the batch file contains the windows script to start few programs automatically.

Comment: So call is the name of your service according to the nssm help.What's the output of `sc query call` ?

Comment: call is the name i am giving to the service and as per sc, the file became a service but still it was not automated.

Comment: what do you mean by `not automated` ? does not start automatically?

Comment: the function of batch file is to keep few programs always running like notepad.exe should always be kept running. now when i am installing the service it doesnot show any notepad ruuning

Answer (score 0):

<s>you cannot just install any old executable as a service, and certainly not a batch file. a service is a program with a specific API which makes it react to service manager calls.</s> ignore that, i just read up on nssm. still, there are probably better ways.

your use case sound rather like you might want to put your batch file in the autostart startmenu folder, to run it at login/startup.

or a scheduled task, if you want to restart it regularly.

one thing to consider, too, is the user under which the script is executed.

Comment: i dont want the batch script to run on startup only. i want to run the script everytime. the script is to kepp running a program continuously like notepad should be running everytime even if it is closed by user it should immidiately run the notepad.exe. the batch file when mauaaly executed the output is fine. but when started as a service it doesnt functions at all.